# plain html in julia markdown

Tags: html, julia, markdown

There is a Markdown module in Julia standard library. However, it is not stated in [the documentation](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/stdlib/Markdown/index.html) how to include plain html in this markdown. For example

```
using Markdown
a = Markdown.parse("This is *important* text with <i>html</i> in it");
# parsed as
Markdown.Paragraph(Any["This is ", Markdown.Italic(Any["important"]), " text with <i>html</i> in it"])
# then exporting to html
Markdown.html(a)
# output below
"<p>This is <em>important</em> text with &lt;i&gt;html&lt;/i&gt; in it</p>\n"
```

We can see that the html has been escaped (at the export step). The output I would like is:

```
"<p>This is <em>important</em> text with <i>html</i> in it</p>"
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Julias markdown parser does not suppor that, see https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/issues/17837 for example.

Comment: That's not exactly my problem: I do not need to parse `<i>html</i>` as html. It is parsed as plain text which is ok, but then escaped when outputting html which I don't want.

Comment: Apparently this is not supported. Html is always escaped : https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/blob/dd738f9ee8dc5875934b22e9f635158b755654ae/stdlib/Markdown/src/render/html.jl#L143

Comment: I mean, it is escaped because the Markdown parser does not parse it and understands it to be HTML, so I would say it is the same issue.

Comment: you're right, otherwise `a heart like this <3 would break html`. And I understand that a html parser in julia base in not something likely to appear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a **workaround**, just overwrite the html parsing function to do what you need:

```
julia> using Markdown

julia> Markdown.htmlesc(io::IO, s::AbstractString) = print(io,s)

julia> a = Markdown.parse("This is *important* text with <i>html</i> in it");

julia> Markdown.html(a)
"<p>This is <em>important</em> text with <i>html</i> in it</p>\n"
```

Comment: this would cause a problem on code blocks because they need to be escaped

Comment: I think I'm still going to accept this answer as the easiest workaround.